# How can I cancel MongoDB query from .each callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I implemented a little NodeJs web server that stores log entries and provides a backend for a web based log browser. The web interface provides also an "Export to CVS" function and lets user download the logs in CVS format. My code looks similar to this:

```
this.log_entries(function(err, collection) {
    collection.find(query)
        .sort({_id: 1})
        .each(function (err, doc) {
            if(doc){
              WriteLineToCSVFile(doc);
            }
            else {
              ZipCSVFileAndSendIt();
            }
        });
});
```

The export operation may take a significant amount of time and disk space in case if a user didn't specify the right filters for the query. I need to implement a fail safe mechanism preventing this. One important requirement is that user should be able to abort the ongoing export operation at any point in time. Currently my solution is that I stop writing the data to the CSV file, however the callback passed to the `.each()` still gets called. I could not find any information how to stop the each loop. So the question is how can I do this?

**UPDATE, THE ANSWER:**
Use `cursor.nextObject()`
For the correct answer see the comments by @dbra below: `db.currentOp()` and `db.killOp()` doesn't work for this case.

The final solution looks like this:

```
this.log_entries(function(err, collection) {
    var cursor = collection.find(query);
    cursor.sort("_id", 1, function(err, sorted) {

        function exportFinished(aborted) {
            ...
        }

        function processItem(err, doc) {
            if(doc === null ) {
                exportFinished(false);
            }
            else if( abortCurrentExport ) {
                exportFinished(true);
            }
            else {
                var line = formatCSV(doc);
                WriteFile(line);
                process.nextTick(function(){
                    sorted.nextObject(processItem);
                });
            }
        }
        sorted.nextObject(processItem);
    });
});
```

Note the usage of `process.nextTick` - without it there will be a stack overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search the running query with [db.currentOp](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp) and then kill it with [db.killOp](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/#db.killOp), but il would be a nasty solution.

A better way could be working with limited subsequent batches; the easier way would be a simple pagination with "limit" and "skip", but it depends on how your collection changes while you read it.

Comment: Strangely db.currentOp doesnt show anything running.Maybe because the query itself is not running, just the cursor, but maybe I'm wrong. Regarding the limit and skip - I think this will slow the things down because theses operation are pretty slow.

Comment: If pagination doesn't apply and operation doesn't show up it looks it's just matter of fetching, so you could switch to iterative approach by looping on "cursor.next()" instead of using the bulk functional "forEach": you could then stop your fetching loop in any moment. You could also tune the transmitted block size cursor.batchSize().

Comment: Thanks @dbra! This was a good idea to use cursor.nextObject(). Works fine now!